# how to propagate 'id's in Kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem in python in the Kivy file.

It works fine with my python code, if I write in the Kivy file:

```
<Generator@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "Generator"
    BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'horizontal'
      Label:
         id: _Type_
         text: 'Type'
      Label:
         id: _Addr_
         text: 'Addr'
```

but my python code does not cognize the 'id's when I create a hierarchy in the .kv file:

```
<Transaction@BoxLayout>:
   orientation: 'horizontal'
   Label:
      id: _Type_
      text: 'Type'
   Label:
      id: _Addr_
      text: 'Addr'

<Generator@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: "Generator"
    Transaction:
```

How do I propagate the 'id' when I create the hierarchy?

thank you

Comment: Add an `id` to the instance of `Transaction`.

Comment: how do I do that? could you show how to change the code?

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What code do you run in python to get your ids?